# Unable to see whole output list on screen in C++ (Not even using scroll)

Tags: c++, console-application, binaryfiles

Ok, I just added a new feature to my student manager program (a console program written in c++) , it is a console application and my program print dates on which particular student is absent in a list format
by saying list format i mean 1 date on 1 line 
this is how output looks like for student who is absent 5 times

```
1. 04/05/2016,Monday
2. 05/05/2016/Tuesday
3. 06/05/2016/Wednesday
```

(Assume dates are correct) 
now since these are only 3 records that are printed on the screen, a user would not require scrolling down, 
but in a case of 300 dates , it prints all dates but when i scroll up I'm not able to reach back to 1st date, for example, I'm only able to see last 147 Records only
and I'm not able to scroll my console window to 1st record.

I know many other ways to solve this problem (like displaying 10 records or 100 records at a time) but I want to know how can i solve this particular problem

please give answer considering me as a beginner. :)

Thank You.

(as far as code is concerned, i can assure you its nothing special, just a while loop that keeps on printing dates until certain terminating condition is met )

Comment: use `less` or `more` or pipe the output to a file and view it afterwards, or increase the scroll buffer in putty

Comment: What OS, and command line interpreter, are you using?

Comment: The number of lines a console window can display is dependent on the console window's settings, and the program generating those lines doesn't control this.  You would need to find and change those settings so that the console stores more lines for scrolling back.

There's always a risk that you'll still produce more lines than can be shown, however, so you should consider alternative methods, such as using fewer lines or outputting to a file.

Comment: Send the output of your program to file using redirection, like this: c++ ./a.out > output.txt  Then open this output.txt to find all the results. If it shows all the results then you need to change the setting of your console as mentioned by @ColinM